# Android Studio not connecting to devices

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am having an issue with Android Studio not connecting to any devices. This includes physical devices, as well as emulators. Everything was working, but I updated AS to the latest version, and now it is not working. The devices still show as connected when I use adb on the command line, so I am able to run commands through that. However, I can not run anything from Android Studio, or debug, or use logcat. What could possible be the issue where adb is connected to the devices, but Android Studio is not?

Even using the connection assistant shows that I have a pixel connected, but AS does not recognize it as an android device. 
[image]

Comment: using `3.6.1`???

Comment: yes. Everything is updated to the latest version.

Comment: InvalidateCache/Restart, try also stopping and starting your emulator at the same time.  You can also do adb kill-server and adb start-server.

Comment: Yes I have tried all of those.

Comment: Same here!  Running Android Studio on a Mac (Yosemite) which I've used for years to develop apps.  Worked great yesterday.  Updated last night, and today can't get anything done because I can't run on emulators nor devices.  Sigh.  That's what we get for updating.

Comment: I just tried running an older version of Android Studio (3.3), but that didn't help.  I remember updating something about the tools or emulator, which is probably still the same even though I'm running an older version of Android Studio.  Perhaps a complete wipe of everything and re-installing from an old version?  (Now to find a way to save my settings....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running on a mac with Yosemite.  I tried running old versions of Android Studio that were laying around which was a waste of time.  So I got drastic.

This is a **really bad solution**, but has allowed me to actually get back to work.

1. Completely uninstall Android Studio and the Android SDK (the sdk might have been over-kill, but I'll let someone else figure that out).  If you like, here's a website that helps uninstall AS. https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-android-studio-on-mac
2. Re-install Android Studio using an older version.  I used 3.5.2 because I liked that color of green better than the new one.  The link to find it: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive (you'll have to agree to their terms before being able to even *look* at the list!).
3. Run the newly-installed AS.  Connect your device (remember to turn dev-mode!)...voila!

Well, it worked for me.  And I only wasted 1 day.

Comment: Yes. I ended up doing this as well. It did fix the issue.

Comment: What a pain in the a$$!  I can't believe we are the only ones in the world with this problem.  But anyway, I'm glad you were able to get back to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Android Studio 3.6.2, updated recently: Directory 'platform-tools' contains a directory of the same name, and I made the hypothesis that this was a bug and that the lower dir should not the there. Using the Mac Finder, I copied all files and directories from the lower dir to the upper one, I closed and restarted Android Studio, and voila, the *Run > Select Device...* can see my tablet, and I could run the app on it.